# Preparing to sell a server

Tags: ubuntu, formatting

I purchased a server about 6 months ago and it's been a huge learning experience.  I'm now going to sell it - I've sold the sites that I was hosting on it.  I'd like to sell it with formatted hard drives... what's the best way to do that?  Is there anything else I need to do to it?  I'm not storing any crazy personal information or anything on it.

It was running Ubuntu Server

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you might not think is crazy personal information still might be useful for somebody else.  I'd recommend downloading a copy of [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) and running it over the drives on the server to make sure everything is really gone.

Comment: I have advocated DBAN for years, great tool. Depending on the newness of the controller drivers *can* be an issue, so just be aware of that.

Comment: If you have trouble with DBAN, a Linux live CD with shred(1) works wonders for the paranoid. (paranoid == dd is not enough)

Comment: I can't remember the RAID configuration I used on the server... how will raid effect this software?

Comment: Do I just burn DBAN to a CD and then boot to it?

Comment: or just pull the disks and sell it without them. That's the usual way you see those things being sold when used.

Comment: @Webnet: Yup, burn it to a CD and start 'er up.

Answer (score 2):

Hunt around for 'Ultimate Boot CD'. You can burn an ISO of theirs to A CD, boot from it and select form one a a few tools that will do a multi-pass wipe of the drives.

Otherwise, blow the dust out of it and perhaps install a fresh copy of the OS, so it's more attractive as a purchase. It helps to demonstrate that it boots. :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are selling the server as a black-box-providing-service, I would suggest that most people who get the server will be formatting the disks and installing their own OS as the first thing that they do.

I also endorse the DBAN as the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Badblocks in write mode would be my choice. Available on every live cd/usb distro.

```
badblocks -svw /dev/sdX
```